# What is the POSIX API for RTLinux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, pthreads, raspberry-pi, real-time

I am trying to write an RTLinux application for the Raspberrypi.  I have successfully patched/built/installed/run the RT kernel with PREEPMT_RT configured on the RPi.  The part I can't figure out is where to get the libraries that provides the Pthread _np RTLinux extensions and the rtl API.  I have found a (relatively small) number of examples like the following (from: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/RTLinux-HOWTO-4.html):

```
#include <rtl.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t thread;

void * thread_code(void)
{
    pthread_make_periodic_np(pthread_self(), gethrtime(), 1000000000);

    while (1)
    {
            pthread_wait_np ();
            rtl_printf("Hello World\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot find the rtl.h header or a library with the pthread_make_periodic_np(), pthread_wait_np(), or rtl_printf() symbols.  What libraries do I need to build and/or install to pick these up?  All of the RTLinux application examples I have found, to date, take it for granted that the rtl header and library exists.